# Regex multiple occurrences after positive lookbehind

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse comments in my source file and I am stuck with reg exp.

```
/************************************************************
 * Code formatted by SoftTree SQL Assistant © v10.1.278
 * Time: 23.04.2021 11:57:15
 ************************************************************/

/*******************************************
 * 
 * some string 1
 * 
 * some string 2
 * 
 * some string 3
 * 
*******************************************/
```

I am trying to extract text

```
some string 1
some string 2
some string 3
```

If my Reg Exp looks like

```
/( \* ([\S ]+)\n)/g
```

it catches strings from the first comment block. So, I am trying to make it to process only second comment block with lookbehind:

```
/(?<=\/[\*]{43}\n)( \* ([\S ]+)?\n)/g
```

But with this reg exp I am getting only line `*`, that is going after `/*******************************************`.

How to combine lookbehind with simple reg exp `/( \* ([\S ]+)\n)/g` to catch lines with strings that are comes after `/*******************************************`?

I mean, these strings:

```
some string 1
some string 2
some string 3
```

Comment: This is a bit simplified, but why don't you consider first extracting the whole comment (say, with `(?s)/\*{43}\r?\n.*?\*/`) and then extracting the lines with a code like `var result = matchValue.Split(new[] {'\n', '\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => x.Trim().StartsWith("* ")).Select(z => z.Trim().Substring(2));`. See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/U3Ywy5).

Comment: Yep, I thought about that way, but my effort is to parse it only with reg exp... Something like an achievement, as a hobby )))

Comment: Ok, use `/\*{43}(?:\r?\n \* *(\S.*)?)*\r?\n\*+/` and get all captures in Group 1, see [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/EZrEW8).

Comment: Or, `(?s)(?<=/\*{43}\r?\n(?:(?!/\*{43}\r?\n \*).)*?\r?\n \* )\S(?-s).*` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%28%3f%3c%3d%2f%5c*%7b43%7d%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%2f%5c*%7b43%7d%5cr%3f%5cn+%5c*%29.%29*%3f%5cr%3f%5cn+%5c*+%29%5cS%28%3f-s%29.*&i=%2f*******************************************%0d%0a+*+%0d%0a+*+some+string+1%0d%0a+*+%0d%0a+*+some+string+2%0d%0a+*+%0d%0a+*+some+string+3%0d%0a+*+%0d%0a*******************************************%2f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```cs
(?s)(?<=/\*{43}\r?\n(?:(?!/\*{43}\r?\n \*).)*?\r?\n \* )\S(?-s).*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%3F%3C%3D%2F%5C%2A%7B43%7D%5Cr%3F%5Cn%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%2F%5C%2A%7B43%7D%5Cr%3F%5Cn%20%5C%2A%29.%29%2A%3F%5Cr%3F%5Cn%20%5C%2A%20%29%5CS%28%3F-s%29.%2A&i=%2F%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%0D%0A%20%2A%20%0D%0A%20%2A%20some%20string%201%0D%0A%20%2A%20%0D%0A%20%2A%20some%20string%202%0D%0A%20%2A%20%0D%0A%20%2A%20some%20string%203%0D%0A%20%2A%20%0D%0A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2F).

*Details*

- `(?s)` - an inline `RegexOptions.Singleline` "dotall" modifier
- `(?<=/\*{43}\r?\n(?:(?!/\*{43}\r?\n \*).)*?\r?\n \* )` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with:

  - `/\*{43}` - `/` and 43 asterisks
  - `\r?\n` - a linebreak, CRLF or LF
  - `(?:(?!/\*{43}\r?\n \*).)*?` - any one char, zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that does not start a `/`+43 asterisks, a line break, a space and an asterisk char sequence
  - `\r?\n \*`  - a CRLF or LF line ending and then a space, asterisk, space
- `\S(?-s).*` - any non-whitespace char and then any zero or more chars other than a line feed char as many as possible (the "dotall" modifier effect is turned off with the `(?-s)` modifier).

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much, Wiktor! I just realized, that I don't know reg exp very well :). It was a very interesting regular expression, changed my mind ))).